# Kohana ORM relationships $has_many and $belongs_to and foreign keys

Tags: php, database, orm, kohana

Working on an old Kohana 2 project and I want to link two models.

I have a model called User with the following ORM relationships:

```
protected $primary_key = 'User_ID';
protected $belongs_to = array('group');
protected $has_many = array('user_address');
```

I have another Model called User_Address with ORM relationships:

```
protected $table_name = 'user_address';
protected $belongs_to = array('user');
```

However I am getting the following SQL error:

```
Unknown column 'user_address.user_User_ID' in 'where clause' - SELECT `user_address`.* FROM (`user_address`) WHERE `user_address`.`user_User_ID` = 2 ORDER BY `user_address`.`id` ASC
```

I can see from the error that it is trying to link to `user_address`.`user_User_ID` whereas it should be `user_address`.`User_ID`. Is there a way to map the foreign key like Kohana 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Needed to add `protected $foreign_key = array('user_address' => 'User_ID');` to the User_Model